# Can't Send Attachments(Images etc) through teams Outgoing webhook to a webservice

Tags: post, webhooks, attachment, microsoft-teams

Iam using an Outgoing webhook in teams to send text's as well as attachments/Images to an custom webservice.
Iam getting the text message data inside the webservice, but i dont get the image data or any attachments when send from teams (Outgoing webhook)

Is it supported?
If not any workaround?

Comment: Do you mean Outgoing webhook in Teams?

Comment: Yes Subhasish.Sorry my bad,mixed up the words. Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The actual card JSON attachment is not sent to the webhook. This is similar to bot scenario.

For images, if user attaches an image, it is parsed by the Bot back-end and converted into img tag, and this should be available in the content as HTML in one of the attachment object. The image itself is stored in AMS (a Teams back-end store) and the source URL also will represent the AMS URL, not the original one.
Sample image sent by user:

```
img height=\"142\" src=\"https://us-api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-eus-d1-abe032166f0b806fe9cb17411e42678f/views/imgo\" width=\"336\" id=\"x_0-eus-d1-abe032166f0b806fe9cb17411e42678f\" itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/AMSImage\" style=\"vertical-align:bottom; width:336px; height:142px\">
```

You should be able to download the image using MicrosoftAppCredential.
Sample code:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                // MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
                var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials("id", "password").GetTokenAsync();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl);
                var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                // You could not use this response message to fetch the image for further processing.

                if (responseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                {
                    Stream attachmentStream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    attachmentStream.Position = 0;
                    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(attachmentStream);
                    image.Save(@"ImageFromUser.png");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks i will check it out. But just to be clear... when you said actual json attachment you meant image/anything cannot be send from upload attachment option .instead (image)  it should be send as a message.(Copy pasting ) Right?

Comment: isn't there any other workaround,in the github issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/901 ,trinetra mentions something around Webhooks are not authenticated, by design. It is not possible to send and access the image with webhook but this works with Bot you can use the bot's token in the http headers for the GET on the image URL. Could you please explain this?

Comment: ,i see the sample is in C#,could you provide a nodejs version of it as well?If any.

Comment: @sree, We dont have the node sample for this currently.